# How to refactor a nested CTE with multiple WITH Clauses to a SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, dbt

I'm trying to refactor a loading pattern consisting of nested CTE:s that work in Snowflake to a similar pattern in SQL Server.
Snowflake allows CTE:s with multiple WITH clauses. I'm using DBT to programmatically  build a view (model in DBT) that collects data quality screenings of multiple tables in nested CTE:s for an insert into a fact table. This works quite well in Snowflake. Not sure if SQL Server will handle multiple CTE:s in the same way. However I would appreciate some thoughts of how to refactor this into one CTE in SQL Server.

```
-- Please note this is just a basic breakdown of the pattern.
-- However. It works fine in Snowflake!

--The first cte encloses all the screens on a particular table
WITH __dbt__cte__dim_customer_screen AS ( 

-- We stack the particular screenings on the customer table

    WITH customer_code_not_null AS
    (
       SELECT ...
       FROM   dim_customer
       where ...

), customer_name_not_null AS
    (
       SELECT ...
       FROM   dim_customer
       where ...
-- We collect the  screening results in the last cte
),  screen_union AS
    (
       SELECT *
       FROM   (
                     SELECT *
                     FROM   customer_code_unique
                     UNION
                     SELECT *
                     FROM   customer_name_not_null
                     UNION
                     ... ) )
    SELECT *
    FROM   screen_union 

-- Next table for screening

), __dbt__cte__dim_debt_screen AS ( 

WITH dim_debt_code_not_null AS
(
   SELECT ... )
),  screen_union AS
    (

-- Finally we union  all the screenings that be the view that will do the insert
-- Into the fact table 

SELECT *
FROM   __dbt__cte__dim_customer_screen
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   __dbt__cte__dim_debt_screen 
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your post, what's your question actually? Does your query work? If not, what's the error message?

Comment: The question is: How to come up with a similar pattern in SQL Server that does not allow multiple WITH clauses in the one and same CTE.

Comment: i think its better to use views or tempTables since some DBMS versions does not support CTEs

Comment: could you provide us with a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Input data, complete query, obtained vs expected result?
I would like to check, but in some cases it's not a big deal as you can query several CTE's at different stages, did you try without really nesting CTE's but 'just' chain them?

Comment: As [an answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110612/does-a-self-join-or-exists-help-here/71111683#71111683) (linked Fiddle based on SQL Server) I gathered several CTE's in n query, I'm wondering if it would answer your question

Comment: That is interesting! I'll check it out! I realize it is hard to give help without a complete query with input data etc. However. I have built this a s a dbt framework containing different Jinja macros that builds the model. The output consist of several thousands lines of code. As Marcio Rocha suggested  above I have tested to create the screens as a view that consists of one CTE (one WITH) to call them in my final model. In this way I don't have to change the DBT framework to much. However. I wonder about the performance of calling  multiple views in another view?

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code:
`customer_code_not_null` is not used
`customer_code_unique` is not defined
`screen_union` is defined twice (I think... there is no ending parenthesis.)

These may also be problems, but it's hard to tell without all of the code:
`__dbt__cte__dim_customer_screen` is redundant
`__dbt__cte__dim_debt_screen` is redundant

It's odd that Snowflake allows nesting WITH statements.  There is no need for it.

Below is the code structure I think you need, but I think this will perform very poorly.  You're better off using temporary tables in place of the CTEs.

```
WITH customer_code_not_null AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM   dim_customer
    where ...
), 
customer_name_not_null AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM   dim_customer
    where ...
),  
screen_union AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   (
        SELECT *
        FROM   customer_code_not_null
        UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM   customer_name_not_null
        UNION
    ... )
),
__dbt__cte__dim_customer_screen AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   screen_union 
),
dim_debt_code_not_null AS (
    SELECT ...
), 
__dbt__cte__dim_debt_screen AS (
    SELECT *
    from dim_debt_code_not_null
)

-- Finally we union  all the screenings that be the view that will do the insert
-- Into the fact table 
INSERT [the fact table]
SELECT *
FROM   __dbt__cte__dim_customer_screen
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   __dbt__cte__dim_debt_screen 
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: Thank you dougp! Yes I was a bit unclear about the code. I just wanted to hear some opinion of how to approach this in SQL Server. I got this pattern with stacked CTE:s from an existing DBT-model. It works surprisingly good in Snowflake. I do screenings of several quite huge tables in one go! Snowflake seem to handle CTE:s differently than SQL Server and, as you point out, probably will not scale well. However. Creating this in DBT with Jinja is really convenient  so I wanted to see if I could keep the pattern as much as possible.